# How come when I click the target, the dropdown disappears still?

Tags: jquery

I have some code here that when you click, and if is the target, then the dropdown will not remove the class (and not disappear). I'm clicking on this element, and yet the dropdown still disappears.

For more clarification. It's a dropdown that does a callback on users name for a search query, and I'm trying to click the users name once it does the callback.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.atwho-container li.cur') === false) {
        $('nav.main ul.right li.main-categories').removeClass('active');
        console.log($(e.target));
    }
});
```

Can please help me figure out why my code is not working? I've tried different variations but it still closes out.

Here is how the HTML looks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have another element inside the `<li>`, such as an `<a>` or `<span>` element, then that inner element may be the actual event target.

For example, here's a simplified event listener that just logs messages. It will only log "don't close the dropdown" if the event target is an `<li>` element that matches the selector.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('.atwho-container li.cur') === false) {
    console.log("close the dropdown");
  } else {
    console.log("don't close the dropdown");
  }
});
```

This works fine as long as there are no elements inside the `<li>` element:

```html
<div class="atwho-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="cur">
      Click me
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But if I add a `<span>` element, the `<span>` receives the click and becomes the event target.

```html
<div class="atwho-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="cur">
      <span>Click me<span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can work around this by setting `pointer-events: none` on the element inside the `<li>` element:

```css
.atwho-container li.cur span {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bradtreloar/5wyoeur1/

Comment: Thanks for your help, with the help of your comment and looking over my own code, I ended up adding && instead of || as I had multiple things going on -------- if user clicks outside it closes --------- but if user clicks on specific it doesn't close. There was not actually anything inside of li.cur.